# How to reference a FormControl in TypeScript?

Tags: angular, formgroups

I have a dropdown FormControl here

```html
    <ng-container *ngIf="formValueChanges$ | async as updatedForm">
    {{update(updatedForm)}}
    </ng-container>
    <form [formGroup]="vestedOptionsDetailForm" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
        <div class="justify-content-center">
            <mat-card class="" [ngClass]="routeAnimationsElements">
                <div fxLayout="column">
                    <mat-card-title style="margin-left:50px; margin-bottom:20px;">
                        Vested Options
                    </mat-card-title>
                    <mat-card-content>
                        <div fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayoutAlign="center center" fxLayoutGap="20px" class="fnol-min-widht50">
                             <div style="  width: 40%;">
                                 <div *ngIf="!hidden" [ngClass]="[routeAnimationsElements,'add-marging-bottom40']">
                                     <mat-form-field>
                                         <mat-select placeholder="Vested Options" formControlName="vestedoptions" [id]="vestedoptions" mask="" thousandSeparator="">
                                              <mat-option selected></mat-option>
                                              <mat-option [value]="Option1">
                                                  Option 1
                                              </mat-option>
                                         </mat-select>
                                     </mat-form-field>
                                 </div>
                             </div>
                         </div>
                     </mat-card-content>
                 </div>
            <mat-card-actions>
                <div class="row buttons d-flex" fxLayoutAlign="end" style="margin-right:25px;">
                <div class="row buttons justify-content-between pad form-container-action-buttons">
                <button mat-raised-button type="button" (click)="goBack()" [ngClass]="routeAnimationsElements">Close</button>

                <button mat-raised-button color="primary" type="submit" [ngClass]="routeAnimationsElements" [disabled]="!vestedOptionsDetailForm.valid||vestedOptionsDetailForm.pristine" (click)="goForward()">SAVE TO QUEUE</button>
          </div>

        </div>
      </mat-card-actions>
    </mat-card>
  </div>
</form>
```

How do I reference and add it to my typescript `FormGroup` vestedOptionsDetailForm, and then pull the value? I put a comment in ngOnInit where I want to write code to access the FormControl so I can take the value from the FormControl and send it via an NGRX action to an API service call.

I want to initialize the FormGroup and add the FormControl that I created in the html to it. How do I do this?

Here is my component

```js
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

    @Component({
        selector: 'dialog-vested-options',
        templateUrl: './dialog-vested-options.component.html',
        styleUrls: ['./dialog-vested-options.component.scss'],
    })
    export class DialogVestedOptions implements OnInit {
        routeAnimationsElements = ROUTE_ANIMATIONS_ELEMENTS;
        vestedOptionsDetailForm: FormGroup;
        vestedoptions: FormControl;
        formValueChanges$: Observable<VestedOptionsFormModel>;
        questions: any[];
        hidden: boolean;

        private policy: Policy;
        private formNames: string[];
        private quoteEffData: string;

        constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DialogVestedOptions>,
            private store: Store<AppState>,
            private questionService: QuestionService,
            private questionControlService: QuestionControlService) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
    //I want to access the FormControl here and add it to my FormGroup vestedOptionsDetailForm


    this.hidden = false;
    }

....

    submit() {
...
    }

...
}
```

Comment: I think you're asking the wrong question, you already have your form `vestedOptionsDetailForm` and you can access it's value using `vestedOptionsDetailForm.value` . However, I don't see any initialization of your form in the code

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm asking. How do I add the formcontrol I created to vestedOptionsDetailForm?

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize your form. It's no need to declare the form control as a property of your class.

You can do it like so:

```js
ngOnInit() {
   this.vestedOptionsDetailForm = new FormGroup({
       vestedoptions: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required etc])
   })
}
```

You can also use the `FormBuilder` service to initialize your form:

```js
constructor(private _fb: FormBuilder) {}

ngOnInit() {
   this.vestedOptionsDetailForm = this._fb.group({
       vestedoptions: [null, [Validators.required, etc]]
   })
}
```

I've passed null as a value for the control but you can pass a default value if you need.

Comment: So by doing that, it will link up with the FormControl in my html through the name?

Comment: Why is it that when I try to select an option through my dropdown, it does not select the value?

Comment: Yes, that's true. You already have the correct implementation in your html template.

Comment: When I choose a dropdown option, it does not select the option. Why is this?

Comment: Looking again through your template, I see that you're not binding properly to the value of mat-option. You should do `[value]="'Option1'"` or `value="Option1" because in your case you're passing just a string. Should `Option1` reference some value from the ts file?

Comment: No, Option1 is just a hardcoded value I'm using. So I should change it to value="Option1"?

Comment: Then using the syntax from above should fix it